# Put value in registry using .reg or .bat or .vbs with REG_EXPAND_SZ type

Tags: batch-file, registry

My reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest]
@="URL:cultest Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\DefaultIcon]
@="%APPDATA%\\musicDownloader\\test.bat,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell\open\command]
@="%APPDATA%\\musicDownloader\\test.bat \"%1\""
```

This .reg creating keys but my problem is that I want to use %APPDATA% and I can't do it with  REG_SZ. It's possible to use with REG_EXPAND_SZ but I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following into a .bat file:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SomeValue" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%SomeVariable%"
```

So for you example, you could probably use:

```
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell\open\command" /v "musicDownloader" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%APPDATA%\\musicDownloader\\test.bat \"%1\""
```

The above is untested but should give an idea of how to add reg values for a .bat file.

Comment: Nice! I changed it to:
reg.exe add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell\open\command /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%APPDATA%\musicDownloader\test.bat \"%1\""
And it works, but there is a problem. reg.exe automatically change %appdata% to hard path of appdata folder. How to avoid this?

Comment: You can use %%APDATA%% instead of %APPDATA% - This doesn't seem to work inside of the shell, but does however work inside a .bat file.

Please accept the answer if it worked for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on the other answer, I assume you actually want to put the literal string "%APPDATA%" into the registry key, rather than have %APPDATA% resolve itself to its actual value.

This can be accomplished by escaping the special characters, i.e. the %'s, in the batch file. You simply replace every `%` with `%%`.

I must admit I've never seen someone use a registry key like that though. They're usually the actual path you want to use. If this registry key is for your own program, you're of course welcome to go ahead and do whatever you like when reading/writing the keys. But if you're trying to use someone else's program I'd question if what you are trying to do is actually what you mean to do. For example, if you want the %APPDATA% to resolve differently based on the user of the computer, you can put those registry keys into the HKEY_CURRENT_USER area, and then each user can have their own value of it.